# Invalid Column name or The multi-part identifier error on where clause in join

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have this stored procedure but I am having a problem with the dates in the `WHERE` clause. I keep getting either "*Invalid Column name*" or "*The multi-part identifier could not be bound error messages*".

I have tried all sorts of combinations of not including the table name or using the alias for the table and with or without square brackets but I still keep getting the same problem.

```
update [SSRSAuditStockProvisionLIVE_backup] 
set [SSRSAuditStockProvisionLIVE_backup].SalesStatus = ss.Name
from [SSRSAuditStockProvisionLIVE_backup] asp
inner join AuditSalesStatus ass on ass.ArtworkId = asp.ArtworkId
inner join SalesStatus ss on ss.SalesStatusId = ass.NewConsignmentStatusId
where (Convert(date, [SSRSAuditStockProvisionLIVE_backup.Date], 103) = Convert(date, @OldestDateToUpdate, 103))
  and ass.ArtworkId = @ArtworkId 
  and (Convert(date, [AuditSalesStatus.Date], 103) = Convert(date, @OldestDateToUpdate, 103))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work.

```
update asp 
set asp.SalesStatus = ss.Name
from [SSRSAuditStockProvisionLIVE_backup] asp
inner join AuditSalesStatus ass on 
    ass.ArtworkId = asp.ArtworkId
inner join SalesStatus ss on 
    ss.SalesStatusId = ass.NewConsignmentStatusId
WHERE (Convert(date, asp.[Date], 103) = Convert(date, @OldestDateToUpdate, 103))
and ass.ArtworkId = @ArtworkId 
and (Convert(date, [AuditSalesStatus.Date], 103) = Convert(date, @OldestDateToUpdate, 103))
```

if you choose to use alias, then you must **USE** the alias in all references to the table.

Comment: Great, thanks! :) I just needed to change the last line to use the alias too and now it works. :) "and (Convert(date, ass.[Date], 103) = Convert(date, @OldestDateToUpdate, 103))"

Answer (score 0):

```
update [SSRSAuditStockProvisionLIVE_backup] 
set SalesStatus = ss.Name
from [SSRSAuditStockProvisionLIVE_backup] asp
inner join AuditSalesStatus ass on ass.ArtworkId = asp.ArtworkId
inner join SalesStatus ss on ss.SalesStatusId = ass.NewConsignmentStatusId
WHERE (Convert(date, asp.Date, 103) = Convert(date, @OldestDateToUpdate, 103))
and ass.ArtworkId = @ArtworkId 
and (Convert(date, ass.Date, 103) = Convert(date, @OldestDateToUpdate, 103))
```